# InheritInChildApplications attribute not recognized in web.config location element

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I've tried wrapping my

```
<system.web>
```

with

```
<location path="." InheritInChildApplications="false">
```

like this

```
<location path="." InheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.web>...</system.web>
</location>
```

But VS 2010 Web Developer Express keeps saying

> The 'InheritInChildApplications' attribute is not allowed

When I run my web app there's an error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> Config Error Unrecognized attribute 'InheritInChildApplications'.

My configuration: ASP.NET 4.0 RTM, VS 2010, IIS 7.5

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am having the same issue ...

Comment: nope, I solved my issues in root app but the application in a sub folder never worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shouldn't it be a lowercase 'i'?

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

I have been using it successfully on the last 4 or 5 projects I have worked on. My spec is similar to yours. I'm still using .NET 4 RC. I also include the system.webServer settings within location.

Good luck,

Rich

Comment: Aaarrrgh! LOL! It's capitalized in MSDN manuals, so I used it as such.

Comment: Ok, the root website is working now, but the subdirectory (configured as an aplication) still tries to load the contents of my 'namespaces' element.

Comment: That sucks. Let me know if it works. It's worth flagging it on MSDN.

Comment: Have you changed the default application name of the sub app?

Comment: Can I put that around the entire Web.config or just system.web?

Answer (score 63):

It could be because you don't have a namespace specified on the root node?  eg

You need

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

not

```
<configuration>
```

Comment: There is one problem with it... The web transforms doesn't work with the correct namespace...

Comment: Thanks - that also cleaned up a couple of other warning that have been bugging me :)

Comment: This worked for me. Should probably mark this is as the correct answer based on votes.

Comment: it seems that this schema has problem in loading. When accessing this url directly in browser it is giving error. I think it should an xml file.

Comment: I don't think it has to refer to an actual file, it just has to match what VS is expecting.

Comment: If you want to get web transforms working again you also need to define the xmlns in the transform against the configuration node like this `<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">`

Answer (score 16):

I think the issue here is that `inheritInChildApplications` is not a valid attribute of the location node in .net 4.0.

The reason the above fix works is because you are specifically targeting the .net 2.0 configuration schema

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

.net 4.0 privdes a different way of dealing with config inheritance.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692.aspx for more details.

Comment: seems .net 4 brought the attribute back?

Answer (score 1):

I use clear quite often to achieve this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
  <assemblies>
     <clear>
  <clientTarget>
     <clear>
  <compilation>
     <compilers>
        <clear>
  <httpHandlers>
     <clear>
  <httpModules>
     <clear>
  <serviceDescriptionFormatExtensionTypes>
     <clear>
  <webServices>
     <protocols>
        <clear>
  <soapExtensionTypes>
     <clear>
  <soapExtensionReflectorTypes>
     <clear>
  <soapExtensionImporterTypes>
     <clear>
```

Comment: I tried this and got the error: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. The configuration section 'clear' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Comment: Just set it above the nodes you wish to clear.  <namespaces>
<clear /> or <providers> <clear /> or <appSettings> <clear /> etc etc etc

Comment: I don't like turning off the inheritance altogether so I prefer to use clear where I need to.